# pgfplots - x axis label show 0.001 instead 10^-3

Tags: pgfplots

I have plotted a fiure in matlab and then used matlab2tikz and pfgplots to include the diagram in my latex file.

This is how I call the graph in latex...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    table/search path={figures},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subimport{figures/}{fig1.tikz}
\caption{this is a figure}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But somehow the x-axis label is transformed in that process...

This is the MATLAB figure:
[image: This is the matlab figure]

And this is the resulting figure after compiling my latex document:

[image: matlabplot]

I don't know if there is an easy fix to that. 
(I have not included a minimal working example yet, but let me know if that is necessary.) 
**Code tikzpicture:**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=2.7in,
at={(1.531in,0.529in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={mycolor2},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
every x tick/.append style={mycolor2},
xmin=0,
xmax=0.1,
xlabel style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
xlabel={xlabel},
every outer y axis line/.append style={mycolor2},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
every y tick/.append style={mycolor2},
ymin=25,
ymax=75,
ylabel style={font=\color{mycolor2}},
ylabel={ylabel},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, line width=0.7pt]
plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{%
0.1 28.5    0.12    0.12\\
0.075   28.1    0.13    0.13\\
0.05    28.4    0.37    0.37\\
0.025   29.6    0.47    0.47\\
0.01    32.7    0.66    0.66\\
0.009   31.9    0.67    0.67\\
0.008   33.2    0.89    0.89\\
0.007   35.3    1.05    1.05\\
0.006   34.8    1.07    1.07\\
0.005   37.6    1.58    1.58\\
0.004   37.5    0.94    0.94\\
0.003   38.7    0.82    0.82\\
0.002   41.8    1.94    1.94\\
0.001   46.3    1.32    1.32\\
0.0005  53.6    1.58    1.58\\
0.0001  54.5    0.95    0.95\\
1e-05   62.3    0.46    0.46\\
1e-06   71.6    0.03    0.03\\
0   72.9    0.03    0.03\\
};
\addlegendentry{Line - I}

\addplot [color=red, line width=0.7pt]    
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{%
0.1 28.1    0.19    0.19\\
0.075   27.8    0.21    0.21\\
0.05    27.6    0.23    0.23\\
0.025   27.3    0.12    0.12\\
0.01    31.7    0.7 0.7\\
0.009   31.1    0.64    0.64\\
0.008   30.1    0.65    0.65\\
0.007   33.4    1.02    1.02\\
0.006   35  1.23    1.23\\
0.005   33.5    1.43    1.43\\
0.004   37.5    0.72    0.72\\
0.003   35.4    1.84    1.84\\
0.002   45  0.75    0.75\\
0.001   46.6    1.8 1.8\\
0.0005  52.9    0.46    0.46\\
0.0001  69.8    0.5 0.5\\
1e-05   71.6    0.16    0.16\\
};
\addlegendentry{Line - II}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: MWEs are not always necessary. In your case, it would be quite relevant to have the complete code for the figure in order to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: You could try adding `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2` to you `axis` options in `fig1.tikz`. But I cannot be totally sure without the MWE

Comment: the matlab code or the one in latex?

Comment: The latex code. Basically, your MWE should contain only what is required to reproduce your issue. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more information. Remember MATLAB is a costly software that is not availabe to everyone

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to include sth reproducable.

Comment: I have included my document class and the tikzpicture code, does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution proposed in comment actually works.

Add `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}` to your `axis options`.

I had to modify your MWE to both make it compilable due to undefined colors (e.g. `mycolor1`) and also to show you what you could have reduced you snippet to.

**Simplified MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.5in,
height=2.7in,
every x tick label/.append style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
xmin=0,
xmax=0.1,
ymin=25,
ymax=75,
]
\addplot [color=green]
plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{%
0.1 28.5    0.12    0.12\\
0   72.9    0.03    0.03\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, yes thank you so much!
And also thanks for the example of the MWE. I always find that very hard. Thanks

Comment: No trouble, happy to help !